# Can military police arrest civilians on US soil?

Tags: realism, jack-reacher

In the movie ***Jack Reacher: Never Go Back***, Jack Reacher has a sheriff arrested by military police because this sheriff is possibly involved human trafficking.

Can military police arrest a civilian on US soil? I thought MPs were only allowed to operate within military personnel.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Military_police#Limitation_of_authority_and_jurisdiction

Comment: I'm sure MPs can arrest anyone, solider or civilian, who commits a crime within a military reservation, if that person is within a military reservation at the time of arrest.  I don't know if MPs have any greater arrest powers than that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Off base, military police have the authority to arrest only soldiers. On a military reservation or base, military police have jurisdiction and can arrest anyone, including civilians.

Movies like Presidio or Jack Reacher that show the MPs arresting civilians outside of a military reservation are not realistic. In such situations it is the policy of the military police to coordinate with civilian police to make such arrests.

Comment: It should be noted that **anyone** can carry out an arrest if the have reason to believe a felony has been carried out. If local law enforcement was corrupt then the MPs were carrying out a [**Citizens Arrest**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Citizen%27s_arrest#United_States) and the rest can be argued in court.

Comment: The term "soldiers" is often considered to refer to only members of the army. Can MP from one branch arrest members of another branch?

Answer (score 1):

No, only on military soil unless they have changed the laws in the last 10 years.